# jquery val - not working as wished on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
    function discuss(thema){
     $('#prep').val(thema + '<div>answer button</div>');
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="quatschen"> 
<div id="prep"> </div>
</div>
```

it is not setting the value of `prep`, nothing happens if i click `discuss()` function.

`discuss` is called here:

```
<input type="text" name="thema" id="thema" />
<a href="javascript:discuss($('#thema').val())"> discuss me </a>
```

if I change `val()` to `append()`, it is working. why is `val` not working here?

Thanks for help

Comment: Read the docs! `val` sets the `value` property of an element; it doesn't change the contents of a `div`.

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/). That will explain what `val` does (and why it "doesn't work" here): "The .val() method is primarily used to *get the values of form elements* such as input, select and textarea." -1 because this was the first google hit for `jquery api val`.

Comment: The `.val()` method is shorthand for accessing the `value` property of `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` fields. (I guess probably `<option>` too though I don't think I've ever tried that.)

Comment: Right - when a reasonably well-documented thing like a jQuery API is not doing what you expect, it's a good idea to go to the API documentation first.

Comment: @Mathletics, of course i have searched. coming not to right solution doesnot mean that i didnot research

Comment: @doniyor "Why is val not working here?" is trivially answered by the documentation. There is nothing to discuss here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.html()`.. `.val` is only for input fields.

```
$('#prep').html(thema + '<div>answer button</div>');
```